# how to design if some constants are used by multiple classes

Tags: java

I've few common constants which are used by multiple classes.

What's the most effective way to design in this case:

1. Should I redefine the constants in each class?
2. Or should I separate such constants in a public class, and use the constants (in separate class) within each class?

Or is there any other better approach?

*Note:-* I'm looking for best OO technique which would be applicable for this.

Comment: I usually use the second approach. All the constants with public static access specifiers. All the constants collected at one place.

Comment: I create a Constants class and have `static final` constants defined. I then use it where ever I want.

Comment: An [*enum type*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html), *a special data type that enables for a variable to be a set of predefined constants*, might be a possibilitiy. What kind of *constants* are these?

Comment: The issue I have with a constants class is that it runs the risk of becoming bloated (an anti-pattern) for a very large scale enterprise project with hundreds (or more) of constants.  In this case, option #1 does not look too bad.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen : My problem is exactly the same. In my project, I've a constant class, which is dump of all constants, which are referenced by multiple classes. So, moving the constants to respective classes where they are used better option?

Comment: If the constant has a deep logical connection to a single class, then I see nothing wrong with putting the constant in that class (e.g. Java `Math.PI`).  If it is really a general constant, then putting into a constants class seems OK.  If that class gets bloated, then maybe you subdivide it.

Answer (score 3):

Constants should be strictly related to some type, they shouldn't just "exist".  A `Constants` class may seem convenient, but it will soon become unmaintainable, not to mention many consider it an antipattern.

It's hard to suggest improvements without seeing your code, but it seems like you need to rethink your design if you find yourself needing the same constants defined in a few different classes outside of the scope of a type.

Answer (score 1):

Providing a Constant Util class is the cleanest way.

```
class ConstantUtil {
    public static final int MAX_SIZE = 1<<10;
}
```

The typical folder heirarchy is like this

```
com.example.util.ConstantUtil
```

Answer (score 1):

If the contants are dedicated to an api define them there. E.g.

```
 public interface TaskService {

     public static final int PRIORITY_LOW = -1;
     public static final int PRIORITY_NORMAL = 0;
     public static final int PRIORITY_HIGH = 1;

     public void schedule(Task task, int priority);
 }
```

If constants are not releated to a single api define a constants interface. E.g. [javax.swing.WindowConstants](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/WindowConstants.html).

> Or is there any other better approach? Note:- I'm looking for best OO technique which would be applicable for this.
>   java

This brings us back to the question how constants are used. Most times they are used to write conditional code. E.g.

```
 public class TaskServiceImpl implements TaskService {

     private List<Task> lowPriority = new ArrayList<Task>();
     private List<Task> normalPriority = new ArrayList<Task>();
     private List<Task> highPriority = new ArrayList<Task>();

     public void schedule(Task task, int priority){
         if(priority == PRIORITY_HIGH ){
             highPriority.add(task);
         } else if(priority == PRIORITY_LOW ){
             lowPriority.add(task);
         } else if(priority == PRIORITY_NORMAL){
             normalPriority.add(task);
         } else {
             ....
         }
     }
 }
```

In this case find out what the purpose of the constants is. In the example above the purpose is to group the tasks or if you think further to order them for execution. Move that logic to an own class. E.g. Introduce a `Priority` class that might implement `Compareable` ;)

You can also take a look at my blog about type-switches https://www.link-intersystems.com/blog/2015/12/03/enums-as-type-discriminator-anti-pattern/.
It is about enum misuse, but it also applies to constants.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to create a class which contains all the constants(i.e, the second approach).

For example:

```
classname :  MyConstantsClass.java    
public static final String SOME_CONSTANT="value";
```

and then use it like

```
MyConstantsClass.SOME_CONSTANT
```

As some have suggested to use interface to create constants then I don't think that it would be a good choice. As using interface to create constants have certain disadvantages as well:

> - The usage of an interface does not allow to implement a mechanism for    converting the constants to a visible/human readable
>     representation.
> - If the constants are an "implementation detail", an interface might    not be the natural place for the value (CodeSmells, ListenToTheCode).
> - Due to Java compiler optimization, complete code recompilation of all    classes using the constants is necessary if a constant changes.
>     Just    changing the interface and recompiling it does not work (this
>     is,    however the case with all constants defined as 'static final')

Please refer:

- [Interfaces For Defining Constants](http://c2.com/ppr/wiki/JavaIdioms/InterfacesForDefiningConstants.html)
- [Interface for constants](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=32)
- [Class for constants](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=2)

Answer (score 0):

Constant class :

```
 interface Constants {
    int CONSTANT_ONE = 0;
    int CONSTANT_TWO = 1;
    int CONSTANT_THREE = 2;

    String BASE_PATH = "YourPath";
 }
```

And usage:

```
if (someValue == Constants.CONSTANT_ONE) {

 }
```

**Edit:**
In most cases use `interface` instead of `class` if there is no need to implement this interface by some class, then it is no need to add this `public static final`, because by default it is `public static final` so your code looks more clean.

Comment: Interfaces should be used to describe `a behaviour`, something a client class might implement. Using an interface just for containing constants may seem confusing for a programmer. The best way is to set them constants into _a class_.

Comment: If all the variables are constant, then it is better to use interface, because by default it is `public static final`, your code can looks more clean. In-fact `Interface` is also Java `class' after compiling

Comment: My Tech Lead uses this approach when defining constants, so 1+.

Comment: Using interface for constants are not considered good anymore. Refer: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=32

Comment: It's an anti-pattern to use interfaces as constant classes

Comment: I like write less do more, but you write more do less.

Answer (score -1):

Design a class like AppUtil.java and and define your constants public static final like below:

```
public class AppUtil
 {
   public static final String IMAGE_STATUS="0";

 }
```

and when you want to use variable use .  like below:

```
AppUtil.IMAGE_STATUS
```